# (Haskell) How would you evaluate polynomial with folds?

Tags: haskell

given a number `x` and a list `[a_0,a_1,.....,a_n]` you should implement a function "`poly`" where the result should be

```
poly = a_0 + a_1*x + a_2*x^2 + .... + a_n*x^n.
```

how would you do that using only `fold`?

Comment: as this has the look of an exercise / homework: what have you tried?

Comment: so this is obviously not using a fold but it has the basic ideas you need: `let poly x as = sum $ zipWith (*) (iterate (*x) 1) as` - so you can either think about a solution yourself or search the documentation for the parts above and try to figure out how to implement this with a fold ;) - you'll learn either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this seems a homework exercise I will only give some hints:

1. Write down a simplified type signature for your function in a file `myfile.hs`

   ```
   module MyFile where

   evalPolynomial :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
   evalPolynomial x coeffs = undefined
   ```
2. alternatively you can write the evaluation

   ```
   a_0 + a_1*x + a_2*x^2 + .... + a_n*x^n ==
   a_0 + x*(a_1 + x*(a_2 + x*(...(x*(a_(n-1) + x * (a_n))...)))
   ```

   the second one is already fit to work as a `fold`.

   One thing to watch out reading the documentation - recently the type signature of `foldX` have been changed to a more general version, so if you are confused take a look at [base-4.7.0.2/Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#g:3) instead of [base-4.8.0.0/Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:3) or newer.
3. load the file into ghci and see wether it works
4. delete the type signature of `evalPoly` and load the file again into GHCi

   ```
   $ > ghci myfile.hs
   MyFile*> :type evalPoly
   evalPoly :: Num a => a -> [a] -> a
   ```

and add that to your file instead of the simplified version.
the last step makes your function polymorphic, i.e. you can then use it with `Double`, `Int`, `Integer` and all types that are instances of the `Num` class (think of something like Java interfaces - if you are more familiar with that)

Comment: For reference, #2 is an application of [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Comment: Thank for the help :) I surely think i need more practise with folding.